# How to suppress TraceWrite Elmah logging error - TrueNorth.Elmah.TraceWrite: GlimpseDbCommand.TimerStrategy is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, redis, elmah, glimpse

I am trying to figure out how to suppress an ELMAH logged error caused by Glimpse.

The error is - TrueNorth.Elmah.TraceWrite: GlimpseDbCommand.TimerStrategy is null

I have used Web.Config before to filter out exceptions based on the message and url error based on the return code and regex expressions. However, since this is a TraceWrite error I am not sure which ELMAH binding can be used to suppress this.

The problem is that this TraceWrite Glimpse error happens on every page request, function, and stored procedure call and is clogging up the ELMAH log feed with unnecessary data.

The current theory is that GLIMPSE isn't playing nice with REDIS caching and there may be a way to get Glimpse work with Redis.

Has anyone had any success suppressing TraceWrite errors on ELMAH using a web.config setting or using a programmatic approach?

Has anyone successfully extended glimpse to be aware of redis caching and not await a db response?

Comment: I know that we already talked about this (through another channel), but you did check out error filtering with ELMAH, right?